# Laravel-sass not working

Tags: laravel, sass

I am developing a Web Application. I am using Laravel 5.3. I also want to use SASS. This is my first time of using SASS. I learned from this tutorial- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-sass. Now I am trying to integrate SASS with Laravel. I just started building project. So I decided to use this one - https://github.com/panique/laravel-sass.

I included this in composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "panique/laravel-sass": "1.0"
}
```

I added this line in public/index.php

```
SassCompiler::run("scss/", "css/");
```

So my index.php in public folder look like this

[image]

Then I run "update composer" command in terminal. Installation worked well in terminal.

So now I need to try on SASS and make sure it is working or not.

So I created two file in public folder.

```
public/css/style.css
```

and

```
public/scss/style.scss
```

Then I created a view, hello.blade.php. This is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SASS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('css/style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="heading">Let's sass. Just change color.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I added this lines in public/scss/style.scss

```
$red: #FF4848


.heading
  color:$red
```

Then I configure Laravel route like this.

```
Route::get('hello', function () {
    return View('hello');
});
```

When I access the URL from browser, it is giving me this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: parse error: failed at `$color : red`
>    line: 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatsuppathein\vendor\leafo\scssphp\scss.inc.php:4108
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatsuppathein\vendor\leafo\scssphp\scss.inc.php(2761):
>   scss_parser->throwParseError() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatsuppathein\vendor\leafo\scssphp\scss.inc.php(121):
>   scss_parser->parse('$color : red\r\n\r...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatsuppathein\vendor\panique\laravel-sass\sass-compiler.php(53):
>   scssc->compile('$color : red\r\n\r...') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatsuppathein\public\index.php(50):
>   SassCompiler::run('scss/', 'css/') #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatsuppathein\vendor\leafo\scssphp\scss.inc.php on
>   line 4108

What is wrong with my code?

When I replace this line

```
SassCompiler::run("scss/", "css/");
```

with this

```
SassCompiler::run("public/scss/", "public/css/");
```

in public/index.php, it is not throwing error. But not changing any CSS. Not changing the font color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses `gulp` to transpile dependencies and it comes built it when you do `npm install` from your project direcftory.

Open up your `resources/scss/app.scss` file and you can perform `@import` statments to your own files.

The `gulp.js` file in your project's root directory contains the `sass transpiling`.

Comment: So I can even remove the laravel-sass, the one I am using now?

Comment: Moreover, how can I link to scss file inside resources from my view file in Laravel please?

Comment: @WaiYanHein You don't link to the `scss` file. Instead, you transpile it, the result of which should be placed under your `public/assets/css/` directory (or something under `public/`).